# jquery-ui-dialog-extra gives error when used with jQuery-ui-1.9.1

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery-ui-dialog-extra to add minimize/maximize/restore buttons to a standard jQuery UI dialog. Its was working perfect when I was using jQuery-ui-1.8.16.Now I have upgraded the jQuery-ui from jQuery-ui-1.8.16 to jQuery-ui-1.9.1 .

Now the problem is when I click 'minimize' button of dialog, then dialog is minimized.But when I click 'maximize' button to restore the size and position the dialog remain as it is and an error is displayed on console: `Uncaught Error: no such method '_generatePosition' for draggable widget instance`.

For more understanding please look into http://jsfiddle.net/S4LzA/5/

Please let me know how to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `dialog-extra` is trying to call the internal `_generatePosition()` method of the `draggable` (note the leading underscore) through the widget bridge:

```
self.uiDialog.draggable('_generatePosition')
```

Relying on internal methods can lead to problems when the library is upgraded (because internal methods may change or disappear), but that's not even the issue here. The widget bridge that allows to call methods from the augmented elements does not relay calls to internal methods in the first place. As far I know, that code should not work in jQuery UI 1.8.16 either.

A possible solution would be to call `_generatePosition()` on the widget instance itself. Try modifying the plugin and changing the code above into:

```
self.uiDialog.data("ui-draggable")._generatePosition();
```

Comment: thank you for the reply..  The code works with jQuery UI 1.8.16 because even if the internal method are prevented it returns "returnValue = this" ( if (isMethodCall && options.charAt( 0 ) === "_" ) {return returnValue;} ). This condition is missing in jQuery-ui-1.9.1